# A problem with my Datepicker system (disabled dates)

Tags: php, jquery, html, flatpickr

I have a datepicker for my reservation system but it doesn't work with 1 example. I have 2 date's for the employee to fill in. If i save the Check-in date(mm/dd/yy) **01/01/2020** and the Check-out date is **01/05/2020**. Then after if i want to edit the reservation data. I can not change the Check-out date to **01/03/2020** because 1 until 5 are now disabled dates.

My question is if someone knows how to handle this. Maybe i need to write code for another system for handling the disabled dates only. But i want to know if someone know's how to do this with **the datepicker only**. I prefer that.

I use flatPickr as datepicker with Jquery. I use PHP for getting the disabled dates from the database and i load that as a array inside the disabled dates function of the datepicker.

Let me know what your thoughts are, and if you have tips and hints you can also answer to me.

Thanks for your time

**HTML code**

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check in</label>
<div class="col-8">
<input id='from1' type='text' name='dateFrom1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off"  />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check out</label>
<div class="col-8">
<input id='to1' type='text' name='dateTo1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off"  />
</div>
</div>
```

**Datepicker code jquery. Dates from the database and code to take all day's between the 2 dates and placed inside the `disable[]` function with variable `$strBlockA`**

```
 $('#from1').flatpickr({
     onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
       endPicker.set('minDate', selectedDates[0]);
     },

     allowInput: true,
     dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
     disable: [<?php echo implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $strBlockA))); ?>],
   });

   endPicker = flatpickr("#to1", {
   allowInput: true,
   dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
   disable: [<?php echo implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $strBlockA))); ?>],

   });
```

**Code that takes the dates from the database and also gets all the dates inbetween**

```
  //Camping Block A
     $sql = "SELECT dateFrom,dateTo from campinginformation WHERE dateFrom IS NOT NULL AND dateTo IS NOT NULL AND dateFrom != '' AND dateTo != '' AND chooseCamping = 'Caravan of camper (kleine plaats)'";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
     $success = $statement->execute();

     $strBlockA = '';
        while ($output = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

               // Specify the start date. This date can be any English textual format
                    $date_from = $output["dateFrom"];
                    $date_from = strtotime($date_from); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp

                    // Specify the end date. This date can be any English textual format
                    $date_to = $output["dateTo"];
                    $date_to = strtotime($date_to); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp

                    // Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates inbetween
                    for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
                        $strBlockA .= "'".date("m-d-y", $i)."',";
                    }

           }


           $strBlockA .= rtrim($strBlockA,",");
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. Unless we have some actual code it's hard to deduce the problem.

Comment: @Mouser Oke will do now, thanks for the tip

Comment: @Mouser Is this enough? Can you help me further please?

Comment: Not yet, since we don't know what data PHP renders. So please replace the php with the actual data.

Comment: @Mouser Sorry, forgot. Now i have. Check it out

Comment: Just as a comment here: the picker works fine when you insert data for the first time. Only when you revisit the reservation (saved data), the dates are greyed out? The solution for this is to create a *new* and a *edit* form. The latter can edit dates and sniffs out dates that are still available.

Comment: @Mouser Thanks for your time. If you revisit the reservation to edit it. You can change the dates but you will see red disabled dates on the date's you chose.

I don't understand your solution completely. So you want me to disable them and make new input fields for dates? But then they still see the disabled dates. If 1 until 5 is disabled. How can i change the date to 1 until 3. Because now 1 until 5 is red and disabled.

Comment: That indicates that there is a design issue here. The dates should be only disabled if another reservation is blocking it. The php code should eliminate the dates belonging to the edited reservation.

Comment: @Mouser I am not getting it, i am stupid. Wait uhm, So if 1 until 5 is reserved. And i make a new resevervation how should that look? So your saying you don't see the disabled RED dates? But how should that work? "if another reservation is blockit it". Can you write it down with examples and more in details? Thanks

Comment: @Mouser You still there?

Comment: @Mouser i put a bounty on it for 100 points if you can explain more and make it work for me?

Comment: I need to know a lot more about your application for this. My time is limited since my regular job is teaching and SO is not a job site, where you can offer some bounty to write some code. It looks to me that you are in over your head with building this application and actually hiring an expert would greatly expedite your endeavour.

Comment: @Mouser The person that gave the question seems to be an expert. I only need a solution for if i chose 2 januari until 5 januari. You can pick 1 januari until 6 januari, that should not be possible. But other than that he fixed that part of the problem there where i can edit my reservations dates. But no worries, thanks for your time typing that. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, you can simply add another `where` condition onto your query, such that you exclude the current reservation from your search, like so:

```
 ... and reservationID != {$currentReservationID}
```

Then you'll only be looking at other reservations, which is all that you need when you are editing one.

---

For the latter issue, do you currently have two date fields, a check in and a check out date? If so, the easiest way to address this will be to use the [range calendar](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#range-calendar) feature to have one date range picker instead of two date pickers, which does not appear to allow disabled dates inside of the range.

If you do this, the only thing you will have to change is that instead of something to the effect of:

```
$startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
$endDate = $_POST['endDate'];
```

you would use:

```
$dateRange = $_POST['dateRange'];
$dateRange = explode(" to ", $dateRange);
$startDate = $dateRange[0];
$endDate = $dateRange[1];
```

---

If, however, that won't work for you for whatever reason, I believe the next best option would be to do a simple SQL query before inserting their reservation that validates if the dates are available.

You could do something like this, just before inserting their query:

```
select reservationID from campinginformation
where
  dateFrom between "{$startingDate}" and "{$endingDate}"
  or dateTo between "{$startingDate}" and "{$endingDate}"
```

If this returns any results, do not insert their reservation, and provide a failure message.

Comment: The first solution works perfect man thank you very much, i am very happy now. The second solution i don't understand. So you mean with that. Before i save a registration with that query i will check if there is a date between start date and end date. If that is positive. The reservation can't be saved?

Comment: I found that your answer solved my problem and KingRichard solved my problem above. The 2 problems that i had are with you 2 solved now. But how can i split the bounty with you guys?

Comment: @Gester The second solution searches the entire reservation list for any reservation with either date between the two dates of the current reservation, thus checking for any conflicting ones regardless of how they conflict, and is an additional server-side check. As for your bounty, I have no idea, I expanded my answer somewhat.

Comment: Do you know how i can split the bounty between 2 people?

Comment: @zbeei am giving it to you and i will LIKE multiple post from KingRichard

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do. I'll try to explain since I don't know your complete database setup.

Your query here is picking all the reserved dates out of the system.

```
$sql = "SELECT dateFrom,dateTo from campinginformation WHERE dateFrom IS NOT NULL AND dateTo IS NOT NULL AND dateFrom != '' AND dateTo != '' AND chooseCamping = 'Caravan of camper (kleine plaats)'";
```

I'm assuming that each row has an ID too?

You should exclude the ID of the current reservation (the one being edited) from this query, and that will free up the dates to be available.

So something like this:

```
$thisReservation = 0; //get the reservation ID of the one being edited

$sql = "SELECT dateFrom,dateTo from campinginformation WHERE dateFrom IS NOT NULL AND dateTo IS NOT NULL AND dateFrom != '' AND dateTo != '' AND chooseCamping = 'Caravan of camper (kleine plaats)' AND ReservationID !== $thisReservation";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i take all the reserved dates out of the system but i filter them by `chooseCamping` Let's say i have camping a, camping b, camping c and camping d. So i take all the chosen dates from and filter them by CAMP. Then i have a code to show all the dates between `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. Then i put that in a variable and i put THAT variable in the datepicker disabled function. 

But i don't understand what you mean. So for clarification, you want me to exclude the ID of the reservation that i want to edit? The dates are not picked by ID but by `chooseCamping`.

Comment: Or yes, if i edit a reservation it has a CampingInformation_Id. I dont know i am confused now haha. Uhm....

Comment: That table from the query is called. CampingInformation. And it has a CampingInformation_Id and the ChooseCamping, Dates etc. You want me to exclude the reservation that i am using. Oh now i understand what you mean... I am going to test this now. Thanks for your answer. I will let you know! Thanks for your time

Comment: Glad you talked yourself through it. LOL. But yes, you get it now. When you're compiling the dates to exclude, simply do not include the dates of the reservation you're trying to edit. That way, _those_ dates can still be chosen, but dates from other reservations will not.

Comment: Very nice thanks. But i can't give you all the points if the second problem is not fixed. This is the edited part of the code that you fixed. As you can read above (second problem). If (d/m/yy) 02/01/2020 until 05/01/2020 is already reserved. And if i now want to make a NEW reservation. I will see that 2 until 5 januari is disabled and red in the datepicker. But NOW i can hack it and choose 1 januari until 6 januari. Because 1 is not disabled and 6 is not disabled. So i have to write a code that i can't include the disabled dates in the range. I don't know how?  Do you know?

Comment: if you have some ideas. Starter points to begin with, let me know oke? Thanks for your time man, i am very happy about this. I love programming so, yeah....

Comment: I found that your answer solved my problem and zbee solved my problem below. The 2 problems that i had are with you 2 solved now. But how can i split the bounty with you guys?

Comment: Do you know how i can split the bounty between 2 people?

Comment: I don’t think you can. But you can give it to the other person, and just go upvote a bunch of my stuff to show appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but hope this answer gives you something hint/ exact answer.
Your Query gives you date which priorly saved for check-in and check-out according to registration ID. once you know check-in & checkout date you able to achieve what you want by below code. Hope it helps..
By using below code, previously selected check-in & checkout date are disable to select. 

 e.g. if you pick 01/02/2020 to 01/05/2020  then these duration are block to make reservation. but you can pick 01/01/2020 to 01/06/2020.

```js
$('#from1').flatpickr({
  
allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
disable: [
    {
        from: "01/05/2020",
        to: "01/08/2020"
    }
], //your fetched checkin date
});

endPicker = flatpickr("#to1", {
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
disable: [
    {
        from: "01/05/2020",
        to: "01/08/2020"
    }
], //your fetched checkin date

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.6.3/dist/flatpickr.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.6.3/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check in</label>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input id='from1' type='text' name='dateFrom1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check out</label>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input id='to1' type='text' name='dateTo1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Where below allow to selected only those date which are previously selected. 
e.g if you pick 01/02/2020 to 01/05/2020 then you able to selected in between dates only

```js
$('#from1').flatpickr({
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    endPicker.set('minDate', new Date("01/05/2020"));
  },
  minDate: new Date("01/05/2020"), //your fetched checkin date
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
  maxDate: new Date("01/08/2020"), //your fetched checkout date

});

endPicker = flatpickr("#to1", {
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
  minDate: new Date("01/05/2020"), //your fetched checkin date (may be same /may not) also assume checkin date is 01/04/2020
  maxDate: new Date("01/08/2020"), //your fetched checkout date

});


flatpickr("#to2", {
  allowInput: true,
  mode: 'range',
  dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
  disable: [{
    from: "01/05/2020",
    to: "01/08/2020"
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.6.3/dist/flatpickr.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.6.3/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check in</label>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input id='from1' type='text' name='dateFrom1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Check out</label>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input id='to1' type='text' name='dateTo1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="date" class="col-4 col-form-label">Range mode check in Check in and Check out</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id='to2' type='text' name='dateTo1' data-date="" class='form-control datepickerChange' placeholder="Open date-picker" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

when you use range mode in flatpicker, it won't allow you select beyond block dates. As I added in last code you can compare range date picker

Comment: Hey Aish, thanks for your time and effort, i appreciate it. But this doesn't work. The dates around should be normal. But if i PICK the date INSIDE the range of 02/01/2020 TO 05/01/2020 it should block it or something. Because now i can choose 1 januari until 6 januari. But your code prevents the user to pick another date. The user should be able to pick another date which is NOT inside the range of the disabled dates. Let me know if you understand this? I will be here to talk about it with you.

Comment: Oke! great! I am checking the other answer now, will let you know if this worked.

Comment: The previous answer works so you don't have to spend time for a solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Aishwarya Could you edit your answer to explain more of the difference and what this does better? I find it difficult to determine the improvements from just your code.

Comment: @Gester I mention the difference what could works in which way. Please check it

Comment: @Aishwarya Thanks for yout time, but i told you the solution is perfect with another answer. I appreciate it.